# Override customizer values on a per-menu base

Tags: theme-development, menus, theme-customizer

suppose I have a few options in the theme customizer, and I might want to show for example 5 different categories listing menus in the site.

In the customizer I can set options for all of those, except that in one of those menus I want something different, so I was thinking about a way to 'override' the customizer options in the menu options.

E.g. all categories lists show the post image, except one where I don't want the image.

Is this something anyone has already done / explained somewhere I couldn't find?